# How do I write a list to a csv and make each element in the list be its own column?

Tags: python, list, csv

Say I have a list in python like so:

```
my_list = ['35.32', '23.12', '34.34']
```

I want to be able to do something like so:

```
writerposts.writerow(["cat", "meow", my_list])
```

The above puts all the values in my_list into a single column though with the square brackets representing the list still there. So the csv looks like:

```
cat meow ['35.32', '23.12', '34.34']
```

where the parts in between the square brackets are all in one column

but i want it to look like with the floating numbers all in their own columns:

```
cat meow 35.32 23.12 34.34
```

This seems so simple but i can't find anyone online explaining how to do this - thoughts??

Comment: Currently, you are putting an array inside of the major array at index 2. It would be better to merge the arrays 
(append your array to the cat meow one) instead of inserting one array into the other.

Comment: @GoogleMac those are not arrays... :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, my bad. I'm actually a PHP dev, but I thought I'd chime in. It is displaying similar behavior to an array in this case though. Inserting a list into another list item slot would not work. The lists need to be combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Python 3 you can use sequence unpacking:

```
writerposts.writerow(["cat", "meow", *my_list])
```

Or a more backwards compatible solution:

```
writerposts.writerow(["cat", "meow"] + my_list)
```